# Maximum call stack exceeded when calling the google maps api

Tags: clojurescript

I have the following js code:

```
export function loadDeliveryMap() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD1r7I_MfQzY&callback=initDeliveryMap';
    script.defer = true;
    script.async = true;

    window.initDeliveryMap = function() {
        console.log("init map");
        console.log("Element is ", document.getElementById("delivery-map"));
        deliveryMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("delivery-map"), {
            center: { lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4194 },
            zoom: 8
        });
    };

    document.head.appendChild(script);

}
```

That I'm trying to write in Clojurescript as follows:

```
(defn load-delivery-map []
    (def delivery-map nil)
          (let [script (js/document.createElement "script")
                ]
            (set! (.-src script) "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD1r7IEvzY&callback=init_delivery_map")
            (set! (.-defer script) true)
            (set! (.-async script) true)
            (set! (.-init-delivery-map js/window)
                  (fn []
                    (set! delivery-map
                          (js/google.maps.Map. (js/document.getElementById "delivery-map")
                                               {:center {:lat 37.0 :lng -122.0}}))))

            (js/document.head.appendChild script))
```

The js function works fine, but upon calling the analogous cljs function, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at ni.eval [as cljs$core$ILookup$_lookup$arity$3] (core.cljs:6891)
    at ni.eval [as get] (core.cljs:6822)
    at ni.streetView_changed (VM1567 js:217)
    at $d (VM1567 js:63)
    at ni._.O.set (VM1567 js:181)
    at ni.streetView_changed (VM1567 js:217)
    at $d (VM1567 js:63)
    at ni._.O.set (VM1567 js:181)
    at ni.streetView_changed (VM1567 js:217)
    at $d (VM1567 js:63)
```

Why would that be?

Something is causing infinite recursion. Something to do with the script variable.

The error goes away when

```
(set! (.-src script) "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSvzY&callback=init_delivery_map")
```

is commented out but then the google map isn't loaded.

Comment: The example is not complete. Perhaps the js loadDeliveryMap runs only once and your anonymous function runs not only before setting up the map, but also in response to an event that's triggered by the map. You could put a println into your anonymous function near the top to get a clue of whether it's part of the recursion.

Comment: maybe the stack size needs to be increased.